# Iterate DOM elements and apply jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have made the following code to convert all `a` elements, `input type="submit` elements, `button` elements and accordion divs that must apply   jquery.ui styles.

I have used prop('type') and the tagNames to find out what control I am iterating:

```
$(function () {
    $('body *:not(script, style, noscript)').each(function () {
        var t = $(this).prop('type');
        if (t != undefined && t !="") {
            if (t.indexOf("select") != "-1") {
                $(this).combobox();
            }
            else if (t.indexOf("button") != "-1") {
                $(this).button();
            }
        }

        if ($(this).get(0).tagName == "DIV" &&
            $(this).get(0).id != undefined &&
            $(this).get(0).id.toUpperCase() == "ACCORDION") {

            $(this).accordion({ collapsible: true });

        } else if ($(this).get(0).tagName == "A" || 
                  ($(this).get(0).tagName == "INPUT" &&
                  $(this).prop('type') == "submit")) {
            $(this).button();
        }
    });
});
```

Apparently this is working awesome. This jquery ready function is included in my asp.net mvc layout page and when I add a new control it is jquery-ui rendered.

But the question is. Have you ever done something like this?. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of using jQuery to simplify a little your code:

```
$(function() {

    // Use selectors to get DOM elements you are interested in
    $('a, input[type=submit], button, select, .accordion').each(function() {

        // Create the jQuery object only once, avoid doing $(this) each time
        var $el = $(this);

        if($el.is('a') || $el.is('input[type=submit]') || $el.is('button'))
            $el.button();
        else if($el.is('.accordion')) 
            $el.accordion({ collapsible: true });
        else if($el.is('select'))
            $el.combobox();
    });
});
```

But a **more simple/readable way** could be something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('a, input[type=submit], button').button();
    $('.accordion').accordion({ collapsible: true });
    $('select').combobox();
});
```

See it in action in this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFH7a/)</kbd>

**Note 1:** i replaced your test checking if `div` has id `accordion` with a css class `accordion` (selector `.accordion`). An element id must be unique in the DOM tree, so if you have multiple divs with id `accordion`, replace them by a css class `accordion`.

**Note 2:** jQuery UI has no combobox widget out of the box (AFAIK), maybe you are using http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Yeah Im using the autocomplete

Comment: Great answer by the way ;)